# Can the PHP interpreter be made aware of PHPDoc type hints?

Tags: php, phpdoc

As an Emacs user, the only thing that I envy about "modern" editors like PDT is that PDT understands types, and even PHPDoc "type hints", e.g.

```
  /**
   * @param DateTime $date
   * @param string $name
   * @return DOMDocument
   */
```

Currently I use type hints wherever I can to make the PHP interpreter alert me if I get the parameter type wrong, but that only works if the parameter is an object. More importantly, there's no way to ensure that a function's return value is of a specific type.

This might be a long shot, but is there any plugin or other way of making the PHP interpreter aware of PHPDoc comments in the same way that PDT is? Ideally, I would like to get fatal errors if I return a value of the wrong type, or if I pass a string where I have declared the parameter as an int, for example.

Comment: Like the question but as far as I know the answer is that it is not possible.

Comment: PHP is purposefully dynamically and weakly typed, so trying to enforce types is going to be an uphill battle.

Comment: Check out [PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/)

Comment: I know some PHP editors do it like webstorm. So it would be possible for emacs. But it's just the hinting not the error throwing.

Comment: I think PHPLint actually looks quite interesting, even though it introduces an extra step. Had a quick glance over the tutorials and it looks like it understands PHPDoc comments, as well as lots of other things.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the [SplTypes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) extension (caution: it is experimental). That allows type hinting of "primitives" (last I heard they are better than primitives in every way imaginable).

You can't make the interpreter force primitives in any other way, though there are unimaginably annoying workaround which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It should be noted that this extension is experimental, may be dropped at any time, and has a great deal of overhead. Further, this is not true typing, but rather is an implementation of object wrapping.

Comment: That is potentially interesting, although I must admit I'm not a big fan of the syntax $int = new SplInt(94); But together with the PECL operator overloading package it could be one workaround.

Comment: @Chris Thank's for pointing that out. I had forgotten (I never use it myself, I just think it's cool).

Comment: I was looking at the quickie sample code I posted in my answer (using wrappers), and even though I don't use it, it sure does look cleaner to not have the primitive type checks at the top of the function. The SplTypes extension does the same thing (type wrapping), and I have to admit that it has me tempted to look again at type wrappers. Slightly. I'm sure it will pass :)

Comment: @Chris Don't worry, we all have off days. I was thinking about using regex to parse HTML earlier today... (j/k... mostly)

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP does not support explicit type declaration or type hinting, use of [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) is explicitly part of the PHP interpreter. Per the [documents](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) on type hinting, only object and array type hints are supported.

That said, if you have a function with tight type requirements, it becomes essential to validate those arguments at the start of a function. If you are very attached to the idea of types in PHP, you can either a) switch to a typed language (heh), or b) use an autoboxing/object-wrapper pattern. There is a significant performance penalty to this, but instead of using primitive checks for type (ie `is_string`), you can create the wrapper class and use type hinting:

```
class StringWrapper {
  public $value = null;
  function __construct($val) {
    $this->value = $val;
  }

}

function requires_a_string(StringWrapper $string_value) {
 echo $string_value->value;
}

$string = new StringWrapper('Hello world!');
```

As you can see, that's a pretty big hill to climb (with creating a wrapper for each type) just to avoid:

```
function requires_a_string($string_value='') {
 if (!is_string($string_value))
  return false;
 echo $string_value;
}
```

My verdict is: not worth it.

You can read some more on autoboxing here: http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/04/13/strong-data-typing-in-php-part-ii-autoboxing-and-indestructable-objects-english-version/
Also, note this RFC for autoboxing: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/autoboxing It has been around for a while, though, so I wouldn't hold out for it.

Comment: Yea, no I don't want to climb that hill either. That's why I was hoping that someone with way too much time on their hands would have written a plugin or module that does this stuff automatically. Doesn't look like it...

Answer (score 0):

It was big discussion how to make type hinting for scalar types:

- Strongly check type
- Try to juggle it always
- Try to juggle it if obivios i.e '123' to int(123) but not '123aaa' to int(123)

But As far as I know now developers solution to not use scalar type hinting at all

[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) says:
Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.